# Are automorphisms of extensions trivial?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Here is a statement for abelian categories which seems so basic I'm feeling embarrassed to have to ask whether it's true in general.  Suppose $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ is an exact sequence with kernel $i$ and cokernel $\pi$.  Let $f$ be an automorphism of this extension: an isomorphism $f:B\to B$ such that $i = f\circ i$ and $\pi = \pi \circ f$.  Is $f$ necessarily the identity?  I feel sure that it must be, but I'm starting to worry since I'm having trouble proving it with diagram chasing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not true. Take $\mathbb{Z}_9$ with the generator $a$ and the automorphism $f:a\to 4a$.

Comment: Specifically, $0\to \mathbb{Z}/(3) \to \mathbb{Z}/(9) \to \mathbb{Z}/(3) \to 0$ with the automorphism you give.  Excellent, thanks!

Comment: In fact, $0\to \mathbb{Z}/(2) \to \mathbb{Z}/(4) \to \mathbb{Z}/(2) \to 0$ with the automorphism $f:a\mapsto -a$ also works.

Comment: @Owen Biesel OK, you are welcom!